# How arguments should be passed into AsyncTask<arg1, arg2, arg3> AsyncTask Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am working on an app that has more than 8 thousand data to be fetched from server for first time and save it to local SQLite db then every other times it will only check for newer updates and save it.

But the problem is this application crashes on first time execution because of the for loop it has for the first time data storing.So, I was thinking about implementing AsyncTask but I have to pass a

> ```
> Response<List<POJOGetLatestData>> or List<POJOGetLatestData> get_all_latest_data
> ```

Response . As I am new to this though I have searched for documentation and reference for this type of argument passing but was unable to find a good resource.

How do I do this? Is there any other convenient way?

Here Is My code that I want to implement into AsyncTask

```
private void saveToDatabase(Response<List<POJOGetLatestData>> response ,List<POJOGetLatestData> get_all_latest_data) {
    if (response.code() == 200 &&  get_all_latest_data != null) {

        flag=false;

        for (int i = 0; i < get_all_latest_data.size(); i++) {
             flag = db.checkWord( Integer.valueOf(get_all_latest_data.get(i).getId()));
            ContentValues wordValue = new ContentValues();
            wordValue.put("id",Integer.valueOf(get_all_latest_data.get(i).getId()));
            wordValue.put("Correct", get_all_latest_data.get(i).getRightWord().toString());
            wordValue.put("Wrong", get_all_latest_data.get(i).getWrongWord().toString());
            wordValue.put("date_time", get_all_latest_data.get(i).getLastUpdate().toString());
              if(flag){

                db.updateWords(wordValue,Integer.valueOf(get_all_latest_data.get(i).getId()));
            }
           else
            {
                db.insertWords(wordValue);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

DB Queries ::

```
  public boolean insertWords(ContentValues values) {

    db.insert("tbl_word_data", null, values);


    return true;
}

public boolean updateWords(ContentValues values, int id) {
    db.update("tbl_word_data", values, "id="+id, null);

    return true;
}
```

Error Log:: [image]

Comment: _this application crushes on first time execution_ could you please add more information? Like type of error of exception raised?

Comment: @GianlucaBenucci No  in different different devices it crashes on different number of iteration. for some devices it crashes on 939 th  iteration and for some other devices it happens on 966 th iteration

Comment: Ok, but when it crashes no error or exception was raised?

Comment: @GianlucaBenucci  have added the error log with question please check .

Comment: How is `db` created and where?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce DB is created in DB Helper Class . I am adding that part in question , please check .

Comment: It is not yet added.

Comment: Added it , please check